# can I use string split with dcast in data.table?

Tags: r

Split a string, build columns with unique values, and fill values according to string.

**Sample data.table:**

```
library(data.table)
(dt <- data.table(id = as.numeric(1:5),
                 x = c(NA, "ab.cde", "co.hij.ab", "cox.cde.kl", NA)))
```

**dcast Approach**: close but not quite

```
dcast(dt, id ~ x, value.var = "id")
dt[dcast(dt, id ~ x, value.var = "id"), on=.(id = id)]
```

dcast buils *some* columns and fills *some* values, but it doesn't do what I want.

**string split Approach**: I can't transpose

```
dt[, unique(unlist(strsplit(dt$x, ".", fixed = TRUE))) :=
tstrsplit(dt$x, ".", fixed = TRUE)]
```

the message says that my LHS has 7 columns while my RHS only has 3. So transposing doesn't work. Maybe I can build the columns and fill the values later:

```
dt[, unique(unlist(strsplit(dt$x, ".", fixed = TRUE))) := character()]
```

And now i'm getting close but still not there. I need to fill those columns with 1 and 0s according to a match (or something) on dt$x;

- id 1 should have a 1 on column: NA
- id 2 should have a 1 on columns: ab, and cde
- id 3 should have a 1 on columns: co, hij, and ab
- id 4 should have a 1 on columns: cox, cde, and kl
- id 5 should have a 1 on column: NA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `data.table` methods i.e. `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(dt[, {x1 <- strsplit(x, "\\."); c(list(unlist(x1)), 
      .SD[rep(seq_len(.N), lengths(x1))])}], id + x ~ V1, length)
#    id          x NA ab cde co cox hij kl
#1:  1       <NA>  1  0   0  0   0   0  0
#2:  2     ab.cde  0  1   1  0   0   0  0
#3:  3  co.hij.ab  0  1   0  1   0   1  0
#4:  4 cox.cde.kl  0  0   1  0   1   0  1
#5:  5       <NA>  1  0   0  0   0   0  0
```

Comment: this is fantastic! it uses data.table. Honestly, it'll take me a couple of hours to understand what's under the hood. Thanks! I love it

Answer (score 0):

One option using `dplyr` and `tidyr` is to split the string on `"."` and put it into separate rows and then `spread` it into wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt %>%
  mutate(x1 = x) %>%
  separate_rows(x, sep = "\\.") %>%
  mutate(temp = 1) %>%
  spread(x, temp, fill = 0)


#  id         x1 ab cde co cox hij kl <NA>
#1  1       <NA>  0   0  0   0   0  0    1
#2  2     ab.cde  1   1  0   0   0  0    0
#3  3  co.hij.ab  1   0  1   0   1  0    0
#4  4 cox.cde.kl  0   1  0   1   0  1    0
#5  5       <NA>  0   0  0   0   0  0    1
```

Comment: :( I get an error: Column 3 must be named. Use .name_repair to specify repair.

Comment: @user16970 are you using the same data as shown in your post? because it works for me without any error.